# how to get current sp user department using javascript/spservice

Tags: 2013, javascript, spservices

How to get current login user department using java script or spservices?
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below mentioned code. You will get the current logged in user's **username** & **department** using `SPServices`

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/sputility.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function() {  
    // get the title of current user  
    var UserName= $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({  
    fieldName: "Title",  
   debug: false  
});  
// get department of current user
var userDepartment = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
   fieldName: "Department"
   });
     // alert(userDepartment);


//alert("Hi");
//populate the field ‘Requestor’ with the current account  
$('textarea[title="Requestor"]').val(UserName);  
$('input[title="Requestor"]').val(UserName);  

$('textarea[title="Department"]').val(userDepartment); 
$('input[title="Department"]').val(userDepartment); 

});  

</script>
```

Comment: Thank U hardik it's working fine.

Comment: Mark it so others can get benefit of the answer.

Comment: Using javascript any idea?

Comment: using javascript for email am using oUser.get_email() for department any option is there

Comment: Please refer this ....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Just copy - paste and run . You dont need import everything library :D**
**Best performance solution :)**

```
function populateDataFields() {
    var data = {};
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            try {
                //Get properties from user profile Json data  
                data.userDisplayName = data.d.DisplayName;
                data.AccountName = data.d.AccountName;
                data.Title = data.d.Title;
                var properties = data.d.UserProfileProperties.results;
                for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
                    var property = properties[i];
                    if (property.Key == "SPS-Department") {
                        data.Department = property.Value;
                    }

                }

                var newLine = "\r\n"
                var details = "Name:" + data.d.DisplayName;
                details += newLine;
                details += "Department:" + data.Department;
                console.log(details);
            } catch (err2) {
                console.error(JSON.stringify(err2));
            }
        },
        error: function(jQxhr, errorCode, errorThrown) {
            console.error(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(populateDataFields, 'SP.js');
```